# How to programmatically moving tab bar from a view controller located inside navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller that located in the tab bar that nested inside navigation controller like the image below (VC that has title "Konfirmasi" )

[image]

those VCs are located in the tab bar index = 3.

I want to programmatically move from tab bar index = 3 to tab bar index = 0. I need to trigger the code from that "Konfirmasi" VC.

I have tried 2 methods.

The first one is using `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`, but the result is not exactly I want, even though the VC is move, but ***the icon*** in the tab bar is still on the index = 3, not in index = 0

The second one, I have also tried to use the code below

```
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let vc: UITabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! UITabBarController
    vc.selectedIndex = 0
    self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

yes it can move the icon in the tab bar to index = 0 and it also show the correct VC, but it seems the VC will be instantiated all over again, so the `viewDidLoad` method will be triggered again.

I want to avoid the 'viewDidLoad' to be triggered again, and I just want the viewWillAppear only to be triggered, like we normally do if we switch from index = 3 to index = 0 manually when the app running.

how to achieve that ?

Comment: Share the actual code snippet where are changing the selected view controller?

Comment: @sarah, your first method is the correct one and if the tab selected is not changed, please check your code again

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ol8LYE20_IzbxYCZTiH89Hyu-jh9YsCI

this link contains a video and a tutorial project that I did to check it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you pushed from tab controller you can access into it.

add blow func in Konfirmasi controller

```
if let conts = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
    {

        let vc = conts[0]
        if let tab = vc.tabBarController
        {

            tab.selectedIndex = 0
        }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }
    else
    {
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```